# How to : Deploy to Tomcat *real* Server through Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, netbeans

How do you deploy a Java web app to Tomcat server, on another computer on network(or internet) , through an IDE like Netbeans for development/testing & production purposes ?

Any feature in Netbeans that makes this simpler ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your build.xml.  You'll need `catalina-ant.jar` from the Tomcat distribution.  I throw it in my build-jars directory - you can also place it in `ANT_HOME/lib`.  Here's what I have in my build.xml to deploy to a remote Tomcat:

```xml
<property name="build-jars" location="build-jars" />
<property name="deploy" location="deploy" />
<property name="target.name" value="myapp" />
<property name="tomcat.manager.url" value="http://server.com:8080/manager/text"/>
<property name="tomcat.manager.username" value="user" />
<property name="tomcat.manager.password" value="pass" />

<taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
  <classpath>
    <path location="${build-jars}"/catalina-ant.jar" />
  </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="deploy-war" depends="war" description="Deploy to Tomcat">
  <deploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
          username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
          password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
          path="/${target.name}"
          update="true"
          war="file:${deploy}/${target.name}.war" />
</target>
```

Note that in Tomcat 7 the user will need to have the manager-script role set in tomcat-users.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tomcat-maven-plugin. An in-IDE support is intended for localhost dev purposes only.